# Multiple mkv files from blender video render

Tags: video, file-format, movie-clip-editor, resolution

This is my first time trying to create a video using Blender, and it's from a 4k camera.  I used the following settings:

```
Video Codec: H.264 
Output Quality: High quality
Encoding Speed: Good
Keyframe Interval: 18

File Format: FFmpeg video
```

The video is fairly long at around 26 minutes, and for some reason it cut the video into 9 mkv files at almost exactly 2gb each.  So I'm guessing I have the max size of video set to 2gb somewhere, but I can't seem to find it.  Any idea where I set that incorrectly?

Also, I'd like to export to a single mp4, or .mov, or other formats, but those don't seem to be options.